# Why is $[\partial f/\partial x,2\partial f/\partial y,\partial f/\partial x]$ NOT a vector?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, vectors, vector-analysis

Gradient of a scalar function f is a vector.

I just read a proof of why gradient is a vector. The proof follows from the fact that Directional derivative is not depended on choice of coordinates.

But the book says $[\partial f/\partial x,2\partial f/\partial y,\partial f/\partial z]$
is NOT a vector.

Could you please explain this.

Comment: Typo in the title; third quantity should be $\partial f / \partial z$.

Comment: The gradient is a vector because the gradient is a vector. It doesn't follow from what you say.

Answer (score 2):

Given a scalar function $f:\>{\mathbb R}^3\to{\mathbb R}$ the formula
$${\bf v}(x,y,z):=\left({\partial f\over\partial x},2{\partial f\over\partial y},{\partial f\over\partial z}\right)\tag{1}$$
defines a bona fide vector field in ${\mathbb R}^3$. But this vector field is not canonically attached to $f$; it has been arbitrarily defined my me through the formula $(1)$. This formula is valid only with respect to the $(x,y,z)$-coordinate system given at the beginning.

Contrasting this the vector (resp., the vector field) $\nabla f$ is canonically attached to $f$ through the formula
$$df({\bf x}).{\bf X}=\nabla f({\bf x})\cdot{\bf X}\qquad({\bf X}\in T_{\bf x})\ .$$
This formula does not require any additional data (like the "$2$" in $(1)$), is not confined to a particular coordinate system, and only requires that a scalar product $\cdot$ has been defined in ${\mathbb R}^3$.